# Regex to match all '(def.+?})'

Tags: regex, scala

Pattern `(def.+?})` matches the first Scala method :

```
object defvaltest {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")       //> Welcome to the Scala worksheet

  val str = "object t extends App { def one = { } def two = { } //Examples one two }"
                                                  //> str  : String = object t extends App { def one = { } def two = { } //Example
                                                  //| s one two }

  val Pattern = "(def.+?})".r                     //> Pattern  : scala.util.matching.Regex = (def.+?})

  Pattern.findFirstIn(str).get                    //> res0: String = def one = { }

}
```

How to match all Scala methods as List[String]
So instead of
`res0: String = def one = { }`

return

`res0: List[String] = List("def one = { }" , "def two = { }")`

Comment: Try using `Pattern.findAllIn(str)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Pattern.findAllIn(str).toList works, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for just one match with `findFirstIn`. To look for multiple matches, you need `findAllIn`:

```
val str = "object t extends App { def one = { } def two = { } //Examples one two }"
val Pattern = "(def.+?})".r
val res  = Pattern.findAllIn(str)
res.foreach {m =>
    println(m)
}
```

Output of [the demo](https://ideone.com/LmfuNy):

```
def one = { }
def two = { }
```